# Trying to send a message to a specific channel using Discord.py rewrite and it isn't working

Tags: python, python-3.6, discord.py

I'm currently working on a discord bot and I'm trying to send a message to a specific channel using Discord.py rewrite once the user levels up, and I'm getting this error:

```
   await channel.message.send(f"{message.author.mention} is now level {self.users[author_id]['level']}! congrats!")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'message'
```

Here is all the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import json
import asyncio

class Levels(commands.Cog):
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.bot.user:
            return

        author_id = str(message.author.id)
        bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

        if author_id not in self.users:
            self.users[author_id] = {}
            self.users[author_id]['level'] = 1
            self.users[author_id]['exp'] = 0

        self.users[author_id]['exp'] += 1

        if author_id in self.users:
            if self.lvl_up(author_id):
                channel = bot.get_channel('636399538650742795')
                await channel.message.send(f"{message.author.mention} is now level {self.users[author_id]['level']}! congrats!")

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        with open(r"cogs\userdata.json", 'r') as f:
            self.users = json.load(f)

            self.bot.loop.create_task(self.save_users())

    async def save_users(self):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
        while not self.bot.is_closed():
            with open(r"cogs\userdata.json", 'w') as f:
                json.dump(self.users, f, indent=4)

            await asyncio.sleep(5)


    def lvl_up(self, author_id):
        author_id = str(author_id)
        current_xp = self.users[author_id]['exp']
        current_lvl = self.users[author_id]['level']
        if current_xp >= ((3 * (current_lvl ** 2)) / .5):
            self.users[author_id]['level'] += 1
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I'm really not sure what the issue is here but if anyone knows the problem I would be very appreciative if you could let me know how I can correct this.

Thanks for reading I've been trying to figure this out for hours.

Edit: Still having the issue.

Answer (score 15):

You get `AttributeError` because `channel` is None.

To fix it you need to remove quotes from channel id like this:

```
channel = bot.get_channel(636399538650742795)
```

This is described here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#snowflakes-are-int

---

Also i see another error on the next line. The `channel` has no `message` attribute too. I think you need to fix it like this:

```
await channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} is now level {self.users[author_id]['level']}! congrats!")
```

Comment: Sadly this didn't work as it returns AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send' now

Comment: It means the id `636399538650742795` is wrong. The bot doesn't have access to it, or this channel does not exists.

Comment: I've recopied the channel ID a dozen times, the bot also has access to this channel because it can receive commands and send messages in the channel as well

Answer (score 8):

I was able to send messages using this guide: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-message-to-a-specific-channel
the code I used is:

```
channel = client.get_channel(12324234183172)
await channel.send('hello')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@bot.command()
async def lvl_up(member: discord.Member):
    """Send a level up message"""
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id) # channel id should be an int

    if not channel:
        return
        
    await channel.send(f"GG {member}, u lvled up") # Whatever msg u want to put
```

Try using that code for the channel and sending the message, then add ur logic. I'm new to Stack Overflow so idk if I formatted that code correctly

Answer (score 0):

you need to put it in an async function

so instead of

```
channel = bot.get_channel(<channel id>)
```

you should do

```
async def get_channel():
    channel = bot.get_channel(<channel id>)

asyncio.run(get_channel())
```

Answer (score 0):

channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, id=xxxxxd)
await channel.send("pong!")

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35007215)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is solved (sorry I'm new to stack overflow) but using this made it work

```
@bot.command()
async def Hello(ctx):
  channel = bot.get_channel(Insert Channel ID)
  await channel.send('Hello')
```

Using this I didn't get the NoneType error.