# Unable to send a message to a discord channel discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wish to send a message using this simple background task. However, no errors come through on my python shell, but the message doesn't send.

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

async def my_background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    counter = 0
    channel = discord.Object(id='791003444726988850')
    while not client.is_closed:
        counter += 1
        await client.send_message(channel, counter)
        await asyncio.sleep(60) # task runs every 60 seconds

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
client.run('MY BOT TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add `()` after `is_closed` in your while loop condition: `while not client.is_closed():` otherwise, your while loop will always return an object rather than a bool and the condition will not be met.

Then Change: `channel = discord.Object(id='791003444726988850')` to: `channel = client.get_channel(791003444726988850)`

lastly change: `await client.send_message(channel, counter)` to: `await channel.send(counter)`

Full code:

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

async def my_background_task():
   await client.wait_until_ready()
   counter = 0
   channel = client.get_channel(791003444726988850)
   while not client.is_closed():
       counter += 1
       await channel.send(counter)
       await asyncio.sleep(60) # task runs every 60 seconds

@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print('Logged in as')
   print(client.user.name)
   print(client.user.id)
   print('------')

client.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
client.run('MY BOT TOKEN')
```

Comment: I am now given the error: ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'```

Comment: I updated the post, try now. Also, make sure that the channel id is correct as it could return that error if the channel was not found with that id.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using code [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49836187/14297304), are you using a login token to run the bot as in `client.run('token')`?

Comment: Hi, yes I am using the bot's token there.

Comment: Please update your question with the entire code snippet you're working with, it will make it easier to catch any errors.

Comment: Updated the post for you.

Comment: You are using the same code so the code itself isn't a problem. Have you set your bot permissions correctly on the server? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discord.html#discord-intro

Comment: The bot has a role with administrator, so I am guessing it has the perms to speak in all chats?

Comment: The documentation may be outdated, try these fixes https://stackoverflow.com/a/62740907/14297304

Comment: Just tried them, still no sign of action.