# What do I do to make my embed send in multiple channels? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I made a ban command for my discord bot, but i cant find anything on how to make it send in multiple channels. It sends in the channel where i sent the command, but i also want to to send to a logging channel for moderators to see. Here's the code

```
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, user: discord.Member, *, reason="No reason provided"):
        await user.ban(reason=reason)
        ban = discord.Embed(title=f"User {user.name}#{user.discriminator} has been **banned** from the server. <a:m_verifyblack:850825891780100096>", color=0xff0000, description=f"Reason: {reason}\nBy: {ctx.author.mention}")
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=ban)
        await user.send(embed=ban)
@ban.error
async def ban_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("**:no_entry_sign: You cant do that!**")
@ban.error
async def ban_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        ban = discord.Embed(title=f"Please pass a user.", description="`.ban {user}`\nExample:\n`.ban @user`,   `.ban {user.id}`")
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=ban)
```

you can ignore the @ban.errors

Comment: "you can ignore the @ban.errors" why including them then?

Answer (score 0):

...just get the channel and send a separate message? (or am I missing something??)

example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59264895/10761353